# Should I add a quick return before forEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Is there any benefit to checking if an array has length before using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Consider the following:

```
const foo = () => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".selector")];

  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.style.height = `${element._someProperty}px`;
  });
};
```

This is what I have in my project. In some cases the `elements` array will be empty because the existence of such elements is based on user-input.

My question is:

Should I add something like

`if (!elements.length) return;`

before calling the forEach method like so

```
const foo = () => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".selector")];

  if (!elements.length) return;

  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.style.height = `${element._someProperty}px`;
  });
};
```

Or would that be considered a micro-optimization?

Comment: forEach will make an early exit if the Array Length is 0. Optimization wise a preceding early-return is not necessary. If you have other  expensive code *after* the foreach that should not be run if there's no element, than it would make sense. Otherwise, not necessary.

Comment: No need to do destructuring, [NodeList has natively `.forEach` in its prototype.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

Comment: That's perfect @RokoC.Buljan as that's exactly what I wanted to know. I also appreciate the tip on being able to use forEach on nodeLists and will definitely switch to that. For some reason I thought support for it wasn't as good as it actually is. You have answered my question and I'd be happy to mark your answer as the solution if if you post it. Thanks!

Comment: To add to the above comments, If interested you can read the below posts to understand how forEach is implemented:
- https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach
- https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/1145487